# Default move assignment calls destructor, copy assignment doesn't

Tags: c++, move

I'm observing a strange behavior I don't quite understand with respect to destructors and (default) copy and move assignments.

Let's say I have a class `B` that has default everything and a class `Test` that has custom destructor, default copy assignment, and (potentially) default move assignment.

Then we create an instance of `B`, assign it to a variable, and replace with a new instance using assignment (where the right side is rvalue).

Two things seems weird to me and I can't see the reason for them in documentation.

1. When `Test` doesn't have `move assignment` (thus its copy assignment is called) the destructor of `T1` object isn't explicitely called. I assume that in this case the idiomatic thing to do is to clean the resources as part of the `copy assignment`. Why is it different when `move assignment` is there (and called), however? If its there the `Test`'s destructor is called explicitely (?by the operator).
2. The documentation specifies that the `other` after move assignment can be left in whatever state. How come the destructor for T2's temporal rvalue (i.e. the right side of `=B("T2")`) isn't called in case B's member doesn't have `move assignment`?

Playground code: https://onlinegdb.com/S1lCYmkKOV

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Test
{
public:
    std::string _name;

    Test(std::string name) : _name(name) { }
    ~Test()
    {
        std::cout << "Destructor " << _name << std::endl;
    }
    Test& operator=(const Test& fellow) = default;
    //Test & operator= ( Test && ) = default;

};

class B {
public:
Test t;

B() : t("T0") {}

B(std::string n) : t(n) {}
};

int fce(B& b)
{
   std::cout << "b = B(T2)\n";
   b = B("T2");
   std::cout << "return 0\n";

   return 0;
}


int main() {
    B b("T1");
    std::cout << "fce call\n";
    fce(b);
    std::cout << "fce end " << b.t._name << std::endl;
}
```

Output with move:

```
fce call
b = B(T2)
Destructor T1
return 0
fce end T2
Destructor T2
```

Output without move:

```
fce call
b = B(T2)
Destructor T2
return 0
fce end T2
Destructor T2
```

Comment: With `move`, you have undefined behavior, because your destructor accesses `_name` which is in an unspecified state.

Comment: It looks like that implementation of `std::string` does a swap when moving. Hence `Destructor T1` is really the destructor of `B("T2")` after it has been moved from. Testing on my side produced `Destructor ` (empty string).

Comment: @Eljay unspecified *but valid* state, so it doesn't go as far as UB.

Comment: Wasn't saying it was UB, just saying it is unspecified state.  As Quentin clarified, unspecified but valid state.  There is very little one can do with it in that state.  It can be assigned to, it can be destructed.

Comment: @Eljay "_Wasn't saying it was UB, just saying it is unspecified state._" But, you said "_With `move`, you have undefined behavior_" So did you say it, or did you not say it?

Comment: When you have `_name` in a valid-but-unspecified state you can do two things with it:  you can initialize it, or you can destruct it.  The code is doing `std::cout << "Destructor " << _name << std::endl;` with it, which is undefined behavior when it is done with `_name` while `_name` is in a valid-but-unspecified state.  (I was confused as to which thing was being referred, my fault.)

Comment: @Eljay With an object in valid a state, you can do all things that don't have preconditions. UB happens when the preconditions are not satisfied. Does there exist for a string any valid state in which it would not be well defined to insert into a stream?

Comment: @eerorika • My understanding -- based on what I was told by my coworker Sean Parent in his Better C++ lectures -- in general an object that is moved from is in a valid-but-unspecified-state in which the only two operations that can be performed on it are initialization (assignment), or destruction.  `std::vector` has a slightly stronger guarantee, but in general that's it.  He did not cite the relevant passages in the standard (and I no longer feign to be a language lawyer after C++11 came out).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Default move assignment calls destructor, copy assignment doesn't

Both assignments result in the destruction of a temporary `B` object, so the destructor is called.

> replace with a new instance using assignment

Pedantic note: Assignment doesn't replace instances. The instance remains the same; the value of the instance is modified. This distinction may be subtle, but may also be relevant to your confusion.

> When Test doesn't have move assignment (thus its copy assignment is called) the destructor of T1 object isn't explicitely called.

It's somewhat unclear what you mean by "T1 object". The variable `b` that you initialised with `"T1"` is destroyed. But when it is destroyed, it's value has previously been assigned to `"T2"`, so that's what the destructor inserts into `cout`. This happens in both move and copy cases, and this is the second `Destructor TX` line in the output.

> Why is it different when move assignment is there (and called), however?

The difference is when the temporary object from the line `b = B("T2")` is destroyed. This is the first `Destructor TX` line in the output.

After copy assignment, this temporary will still hold the `"T2"` value, so that's what you see in the destructor.

After move assignment, the temporary is no longer guaranteed to contain `"T2"`, but rather it is left in a valid but unspecified state (as described in specification of `std::string`), so output could be anything. In this case it happened to be `"T1"`. (Based on this result, we might make a guess that the move assignment operator of the string may have been implemented by swapping the internal buffers. This observation is not a guaranteed behaviour).

> The documentation specifies that the other after move assignment can be left in whatever state. How come the destructor for T2's temporal rvalue (i.e. the right side of =B("T2")) isn't called in case B's member doesn't have move assignment?

The destructor of the temporary *is* called. The temporary simply is no longer in the state described by "contains `"T2"`" after it has been moved from.